# How to open a new default browser window in Python when the default is Chrome

Tags: python, browser

I have been looking for a way to open a new default browser window from inside Python code.

According to the documentation **webbrowser.open_new(url)**
Should do that. Unfortunately in case Chrome is the default browser it only opens a new tab.
Is there any way to open the default browser (without knowing what that browser is)?

Answer (score 6):

Give this a whirl:

```
import subprocess
command = "cmd /c start chrome http://www.ebay.com --new-window"
subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

I have a feeling it's not Python's fault. Firefox and Chrome (and probably IE) all intercept calls to open new windows and changes them to new tabs. Check the settings in your browser for interpreting those calls.

Answer (score 1):

```
import subprocess

def open(url):
    cmd = "open " + url
    print(cmd)
    subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
webbrowser.open('http://www.google.com', new=1)
```

or

```
webbrowser.open_new('http://www.google.com')
```

Comment: This still opens the browser as a new tab, not as a new window.