# Python: generic webbrowser.get().open() for chrome.exe does not work

Tags: python, google-chrome, generics, browser

I am on Python 2.7 (Win 8.1 x64) and I want to open a URL in Chrome.
As Chrome is only natively supported in 3.3+, I was trying a generic call:

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.get("C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe %s").open("http://google.com")
```

The path is correct and print does give me a Handler:

```
"<webbrowser.GenericBrowser object at 0x0000000002D26518\>"
```

However, the open() - preferably open_new_tab()) - function does not work. It returns False.

If I run the command

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" "https://google.com"
```

in windows run dialog, it does do work, though.

---

If I set Chrome as standard browser and run

```
webbrowser.get().open("http://google.com")
```

it does work, but it's not what I want.

Has anyone an idea what's going wrong?

Comment: What happens when you do `import subprocess; subprocess.Popen([r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe', 'https://google.com']).wait()`?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: This actually works. :-)

Comment: Yes, and dano explained what goes wrong; I didn't realise `shlex` would do the wrong thing on Windows.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to use unix-style paths in the `webbrowser.get` call:

```
webbrowser.get("C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe %s").open("http://google.com")
```

This is because `webbrowser` internally does a `shlex.split` on the path, which will just erase Windows-style path separators:

```
>>> cmd = "C:\\Users\\oreild1\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe %s"
>>> shlex.split(cmd)
['C:Usersoreild1AppDataLocalGoogleChromeApplicationchrome.exe', '%s']
>>> cmd = "C:/Users/dan/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe %
s"
>>> shlex.split(cmd)
['C:/Users/dan/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe', '%s']
```

`shlex` will actually do the right thing here if given the `posix=False` keyword argument, but `webbrowser` won't supply that, even on Windows. This is arguably a bug in `webbrowser`.

Comment: Sounds like something that needs reporting to the [Python bug tracker](http://bugs.python.org/); I cannot find any pre-existing issues.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I was in the process of filing one :)

Comment: Thanks, @dano: [Issue22025 - webbrowser.get(command_line) does not support Windows-style path separators](http://bugs.python.org/issue22025)

Comment: python 3.6 windows7: did not work for me (URL is open in default browser)

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to switch to Unix-style paths -- simply quote the executable.

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.get('"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" %s').open('http://google.com')
```

Answer (score 2):

Following the suggestions above and working on Windows, to enable Firefox I have changed (and un-commented) the following line in the config file (note the %s at the end):

c.NotebookApp.browser = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe %s'

This worked for me.
Thanks

Comment: What config file do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

**Worked for me**

code snippet:

```
import webbrowser

chrome_path = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe %s'
webbrowser.get(chrome_path).open('http://google.com')
```

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, you don't need to use UNIX-style path.  Just wrap the raw string path to `google.exe` in escaped quotes, and append `%s` token after it, within an [f-string](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals):

```py
import webbrowser

url = "https://docs.python.org/3/library/webbrowser.html"
chrome = r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
webbrowser.get(f"\"{chrome}\" %s").open_new_tab(url)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```py
import webbrowser

chrome_path = "path_where_chrome_is_located"
webbrowser.register('chrome', None, webbrowser.BackgroundBrowser(chrome_path))

webbrowser.get('chrome').open('url')
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however in it's current state it's not formatted very well. Also, looking at the question and the accepted answer, the actual problem the asker was having was with the chrome path itself, which your answer doesn't currently address.