# Cannot open new Jupyter Notebook [Permission Denied]

Tags: python, ubuntu, jupyter-notebook

I have installed Jupyter Notebook on ubuntu 16.04 using pip3. I can execute `jupyter notebook` command. It opens and shows a list of current path directories.

But I cannot create a new notebook(**Python3**). It says

> Unexpected error while saving file: Deep Learning/NN/Untitled.ipynb [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/ubuntu/.local/share/jupyter/notebook_secret'

Answer (score 82, accepted):

change the **ownership** of the `~/.local/share/jupyter` directory from **root** to **user**.

```
sudo chown -R user:user ~/.local/share/jupyter
```

see here: https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/8997

The first `user` before the colon is your username, the second `user` after the colon is your group. If you get `chown: [user]: illegal group name`, find your group with `groups`, or specify no group with `sudo chown user: ~/.local/share/jupyter`.

**EDIT**: Added `-R` option in comments to the answer. You have to change ownership of all files inside this directory (or inside `~/.jupyter/`, wherever it gives you PermissionError) to your user to make it work.

If this fails, change the ownership of the directory you want to create the notebook in. For `mydir`:

```
sudo chown -R user:user mydir/*
```

Note that I replaced `user:user` with `bexgboost:root` where `bexgboost` is my UNIX username.

Comment: sudo chown -R user:user ~/.local/share/jupyter

Comment: How do we do this in windows?

Comment: I had to logout and login on ubuntu to make it work.

Comment: There is no such directory on my system. I use snap to install jupyter.

Comment: On CentOS7, I had this complaining about a `/run/user/0/jupyter`. Changed owner for `/run/user/0/`

Answer (score 18):

In my opinion, it is a good practice to run Jupyter in a dedicated workbook folder.

```
$ mkdir jupyter_folder
$ jupyter-notebook --notebook-dir jupyter_folder
```

where 'jupyter_folder' is a folder in my home.

This method works without any permission issues.

Comment: After trying everything on chmod and chown finally this way it worked.

Comment: Following a cue from this, I changed the permissions on the folder containing the ipynb files and it worked.

Comment: This works perfectly in ubuntu 22, with everything as snaps. Set an alias in your ~.zshr or .bashrc or have an alias for each major project

Answer (score 12):

Tried everything that was suggested but finally this helped me:

```
sudo jupyter notebook --allow-root
```

In my case, it didn't start the browser by itself. So just copy the link from terminal and open it by yourself.

**Update:**
Change folder(.local) permissions by this command:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 .local
```

Comment: As above - please do not use `chmod 777`!  This is a real security issue.

Comment: NOOO! chmod 777 on `.local` folder is a horrible idea. You are letting everyone modify and execute your binaries!

Comment: (to elaborate): your `.local` folder should always have permissions `700` which basically allows you to do everything and you alone

Answer (score 7):

On Ubuntu, 'permission denied' may appear when browser is installed as a 'snap'. I had this problem. I edited config file to open a regular browser and it worked.

[How to change the default browser used by the ipython/jupyter notebook in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35229604/how-to-change-the-default-browser-used-by-the-ipython-jupyter-notebook-in-linux)

Comment: Chromium was "converted" to snap while upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04. That was exactly the reason of "permission" issue. I set the default browser to /usr/bin/firefox as explained in the linked answer and ... now it works fine!

Comment: This is a problem now that Ubuntu 22.04 installs firefox via 'snap'...

Answer (score 5):

The top answer here didn't quite fix the problem, although it's probably a necessary step:

```
sudo chown -R user:user ~/.local/share/jupyter
```

(user should be whoever is the logged in user running the notebook server)
This changes the folder owner to the user running the server, giving it full access.

After doing this, the error message said it didn't have permission to create the checkpoint file in ~/.ipynb_checkpoints/ so I also changed ownership of that folder (which was previously root)

```
sudo chown -R user:user ~/.ipynb_checkpoints/
```

And then I was able to create and save a notebook!

Comment: For those whose error message is ```Permission denied: .ipynb_checkpoints```, this is the solution. Basically change the ownership to current user, who will be able to create and save checkpoints.

Answer (score 3):

1. Open Anaconda prompt
2. Go to `C:\Users\your_name`
3. Write `jupyter trust untitled.ipynb`
4. Then, write `jupyter notebook`

Comment: giver same permission denie

Answer (score 2):

It might be a trust issue. 
Command-line
jupyter trust /path/to/notebook.ipynb
here is the documentation link :
http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html#security-in-notebook-documents

Answer (score 1):

I had the very same issue running Jupyter.  After chasing my tail on permissions, I found that everything cleared up after I changed ownership on the directory where I was trying to run/store my notebooks.  Ex.:  I was running my files out of my ~/bash dir.  That was root:root; when I changed it to jim:jim....no more errors.

Answer (score 1):

I had to run chown recursively for all subfolders With /* . Than it worked:

```
sudo chown -R user:usergroup /home/user/.local/share/jupyter/*
```

Comment: You don't need `/*` - the `-R` switch should be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the problem is in the last release, so

```
pip install notebook==5.6.0
```

must solve the problem!

Answer (score 1):

Try running "~/anaconda3/bin/jupyter notebook" instead of "jupyter notebook".
This resolved the problem for me. No more getting 'permission denied' error.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a configuration file: `jupyter notebook --generate-config`.
2. Edit a configuration file: `sudo gedit /home/<USERNAME>/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py` (You can use `vim`, `nano` or anything else instead of `gedit`)
3. Uncomment a line and change the default value:

BEFORE: `# c.NotebookApp.use_redirect_file = True`

AFTER: `c.NotebookApp.use_redirect_file = False`

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
-> uninstalled Jupyter
-> install jupyter in Python36 folder
-> open Jupyter from command prompt instead of git bash.
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to install or uninstall anything.
if you are using python 2 use pip to install and upgrade. But if you want to use python3 then follow the steps below:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip python3-dev
```

## then in terminal use this

```
pip3 install -U jupyter
```

## final step is to launch jupyter notebook so,in terminal just type

```
jupyter notebook
```

all the issues or problems of premissions etc will be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it turned out my windows password had changed since I shared my drive with docker.

The fix was to rest my credentials in docker `settings -> shared drives -> reset credentials` and then reshare my drive.

[image: docker reset credentials]

Answer (score 0):

Executing the script below worked for me.

```
sudo chown $USER /home/$USER/.jupyter
```

Answer (score 0):

In windows, I copied, what I think is a snapshot:

```
.~SomeAmazingNotebook.ipynb
```

renamed it:

```
SomeAmazingNotebook.ipynb
```

and could open it.

Answer (score 0):

None of the above worked for me but the below did:

```
sudo chown -R user: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/share/jupyter/
```

Where user is your username.

Answer (score 0):

I was launching it from the root dir "/" for which I was lacking the write permission and hence file creation failed as below

```
Unexpected error while saving file: Untitled.ipynb [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/Untitled.ipynb'
```

Once after I re-launched it from other dir , I was able to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

I tried opening from the Python folder and it helped.

`C:\Users\Julia>appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe -m jupyter notebook`

Answer (score 0):

Try creating the notebook in the /home/ubuntu folder

Answer (score 0):

I closed notebook page and:

1. I killed notebook kernel, since I was using DockerSpawner I needed to delete notebook's container
2. I deleted user jupyter directory by running `rm -rf ~/.local/share/jupyter`

When I tried to create new notebook next time, it started working

Answer (score 0):

A complicated problem this one.. but finally I found a solution.

You need to generate a config file:

**jupyter notebook --generate-config**

Its created in the .jupyter directory.
If its hidden, do a CTRL+H to unhide the files.
Look for c.NotebookApp.use_redirect_file and make it like this:

**c.NotebookApp.use_redirect_file = False.**

Make sure to remove the # before the line. Otherwise it won't work.
Done! :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by changing the owner of my current folder. Whenever we type `jupyter notebook` on terminal, it always opens up in the current path (which we are pointing to via terminal), so we just have to change the owner to current user and then if you click on "new notebook", it will create one for you without giving permission denied error.

Answer (score 0):

My os is Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. When I use Chrome, which was downloaded from official site. I solved this problem. Perhaps this is because Firefox and chromium on Ubuntu are base on Snap.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the accepted answer in Ubuntu 22.04 answer, but it didn't work for me which I discovered was because Firefox is packaged as a snap package in Ubuntu 22.04. I circumvented this obstacle by installing Web (Web browser for GNOME) with this command:

```
sudo apt install epiphany
```

Create `jupyter_notebook_config.py` by:

```
jupyter notebook --generate-config # type y for yes at the prompt
```

Then open `~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py` for editing in a text editor and change:

```
# c.NotebookApp.browser = ''
```

to:

```
c.NotebookApp.browser = '/usr/bin/epiphany'
```

Don't forget to delete the # so it's not a comment anymore. Inspiration for these last 2-3 steps goes to https://stackoverflow.com/a/35578527/. You can use a different web browser if you don't like Web as long as it's not a snap package and you change the path from `/usr/bin/epiphany` to the path to your web browser which you can find by running a command of the form `which my-web-browser`.

It still won't work though, so you have to do one more step. It's the same as in the accepted answer to this question. Change the ownership of the `~/.local/share/jupyter` directory from **root** to **user**. Instead of **user** in the below command replace it with your own username that you login with.

```
sudo chown -R user:user ~/.local/share/jupyter
```

Answer (score -1):

- List item
- List item

this problem of not able to open jupyter notebook is like Corona virus.I came across several complaints-including my own.I use windows 10.

Atlast after struggling for 3 days i came across this wonderful foolproof solution:-

1.The jupyter folder is created at path:-
   C:\Users\deviv_000\AppData\Roaming\jupyter
   your name will replace->deviv_000

2.Go to cmd and write : 
cd  C:\Users\deviv_000\AppData\Roaming\jupyter
  this will take cmd to that folder.

3.Now create manually a file as untitled.ipynb in jupyter folder.

4.Come back to cmd and write:
  jupyter trust untitled.ipynb

5.After cmd performs this operation now write:-
jupyter notebook

```
SUCCESS!!- your notebook will appear in the next tab.I used chrome.
```

Regards

Comment: This concerns Ubuntu, not Windows so this answer is not relevant.

Answer (score -1):

I encountered same problem when I installed latest version of anaconda navigator 64 bit on windows 10.

I got to know that ***INSTALLING 32 BIT VERSION ON WINDOWS 10*** will solve the issue.
It worked for me. Jupyter is running smoothly now.

Answer (score -1):

An easy way is to run your terminal in the mode of "Administrator"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

On a Windows machine run the python command prompt as administrator.  That should resolved the permissions issue when creating a new python 3 notebook.

Answer (score -2):

Based on my experience on Ubuntu **18.04**:

**1. Check Jupyter installation**

first of all make sure that you have **installed** and/or **upgraded** Jupyter-notebook (also for virtual-environment):

```
pip install --upgrade jupyter
```

**2. Change the Access Permissions** (Use with **Caution**!)

then try to change the access permission for you

```
sudo chmod -R 777 ~/.local
```

where 777 is a three-digit representation of the access permission. In sense that each of the digits representing short format of the binary one (e.g. 7 for 111). 
So, 777 means that we set permission access to read, write and execute to 1 for all users (*Owner*, *Group* or *Other*)

**Example.1**

777 : 111 111 111

or

777 : rwx-rwx-rwx

**Example.2**

755 : 111 101 101

- Owner: rwx=4+2+1=7
- Group: r-x=4+0+1=5
- Other: r-x=4+0+1=5

(More about *chmod* : [File Permissions and attributes](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/File_permissions_and_attributes))

**3. Run jupyter**

afterwards run your jupyter notebook:

```
jupyter-notebook
```

Note: (These steps also solve your Visual-Studio code (**VS-Code**) problems regarding permissions while using **ipython** and **jupyter** for **python-interactive-console**.)

Comment: I totally explained what chmod 777 does. It is up to you to give those permissions or not. (refer to provided references for more security options)

Comment: I am going to point out that you are changing the permissions on _an entire directory_ that generally contains much more than just the jupyter files you are interested in.  This creates all kinds of security issues.  Using `chmod 777` is just bad practice in general.  You need to root cause the error rather than just changing the directory to be permissive like this.