# error loading jupyter notebook permission denied: ipynb

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I was working in a jupyter notebook until it froze. It wouldn't save or shut down so I restarted my computer. I launched jupyter notebook from an anaconda prompt, my folder directory opens per usual. When i tried to open the notebook from before, I get an error loading screen that says permission denied: (name of notebook).ipynb. I hit close and the notebook shuts down.

I checked the folder permissions, I have full control. I can create a new ipynb without any issues. I can open other notebooks without any problem in the same folder. I tried to run a trust notebook through the anaconda prompt and it says the notebook is missing.

I need to recover this particular notebook as it has all my work. Help! Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

I work in the anaconda prompt in an environment other than the root, so [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46272880/cannot-open-new-jupyter-notebook-permission-denied) using sudo chmod doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I had possibly the same problem. In my case the problem was that jupyter notebook must have crashed or had some problem whilst autosaving.

As a result, in the folder where the notebook is saved there's a temporary file called ".~nameofnotebook.ipynb".

This file didn't show up in jupyter notebook, but only in the explorer. I deleted the notebook file and renamed the temporary file to delete the ".~" prefix. Make sure to save a copy of the notebook file before deleting anything in case your problem is different.

The renamed temporary file opens fine and none of my data was lost.

Comment: yeah it actually works just click on that file you recently created

Answer (score 0):

Change the name of the file and you are good to go bro..

Comment: Please provide more details.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Changing the file name of the checkpoint file inside .ipynb_checkpoints folder and opening that file using jupyter lab worked for me. I assume the same is true for jupyter notebooks as it is just a regular notebook file at that point with all the data from the last checkpoint. The file with the name .~name-of-the-file.ipynb can be safely deleted.