# Anaconda "Permission denied: Untitled.ipynb" error

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I just downloaded Anaconda on my computer at work and I was looking to open a jupyter notebook. I am at the Anaconda Prompt and type in "jupyter notebook." After this I am prompted to the jupyter interface, I click "new" in the upper right hand corner and I click "python 3." Right after this an error message come up "Permission denied: Untitled.ipynb." I am not too sure what to do, for a little background I have python 3.8 installed, the one that came with Anaconda. I will also attach a screenshot as to indicate what I am seeing.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbTXQ.png)

Comment: Run it as administrator.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot open new Jupyter Notebook \[Permission Denied\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46272880/cannot-open-new-jupyter-notebook-permission-denied)

Comment: No, they're different errors.

Comment: I know this is quite old, but did you ever figure it out? I'm running into the same error.