# How to grant Access for File Handling in Jupyter Notebook? [Permission Denied Error]

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I tried to read  a file from directory.
Jupyter threw a **permission error [Errno 13]**

The code

```
data = pd.read_csv("D:/Sies Files/sem2/Machine Learning/Practicals/Dataset")
```

print(data,"n")

The Error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
PermissionError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-0c5a5bfd77a7> in <module>
----> 1 data = pd.read_csv("D:/Sies Files/sem2/Machine Learning/Practicals/Dataset")
      2 print(data,"n")

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'D:/Sies Files/sem2/Machine Learning/Practicals/Dataset'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't read a folder/path .You need to give something like `path+filename` You can use below code where yourFileName.csv represents you want to read

```
data = pd.read_csv("D:/Sies Files/sem2/Machine Learning/Practicals/Dataset/yourFileName.csv")
```

Answer (score 3):

change the ownership of the directory from root to user

see here [Errno 13] Permission denied : https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/8997

and here : [Cannot open new Jupyter Notebook [Permission Denied]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46272880/cannot-open-new-jupyter-notebook-permission-denied)

You have to change the ownership of your files inside that directory or inside jupyter files, wherever it gives you PermissionError to make it work

Answer (score 0):

try doing -
`data = pd.read_csv(r"D:/Sies Files/sem2/Machine Learning/Practicals/Dataset/yourFileName.csv")`