# Cannot open Jupyter Notebook in Ubuntu system

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am trying to open Jupyter Notebook from Ubuntu terminal, but it fails to start because of permission issues. Specifically, a webpage would open up in the Firefox browser, which displays the error message

```
The file at /home/<user>/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-61219-open.html is not readable.
```

I have found an similar issue at [Cannot open new Jupyter Notebook [Permission Denied]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46272880/cannot-open-new-jupyter-notebook-permission-denied), which suggests that I should change the ownership of the folder by typing the command

```
sudo chown -R <user>:<user> ~/.local/share/jupyter
```

However, this did not work for me. I have also tried other suggestions from https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/3608. The commands `sudo jupyter-notebook --allow-root` or `sudo jupyter notebook --allow-root` result in errors saying that the commands are not found. I have also tried `chmod -R 777 <my directory>`, and the same error still occur.

I realize that at runtime, Jupyter Notebook produces a .html file and a .json file in `/home/<user>/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/`, the directory where the permission error is reported. By running `ls -l` on this directory during runtime, it seems like I (both the user and the group) do not have execute permission on these two files, but have read and write permissions. Is this the cause to my problem? How can I fix this?

(Additionally, I installed Jupyter Notebook using pip inside the conda base environment, and all the above commands are executed in the same environment)

Specs:

- Ubuntu version: 21.10
- Jupyter Notebook version: 6.4.5
- Miniconda version: 4.10.3
- Python version: 3.9.5
- Web browser: Firefox

Answer (score 3):

Try changing the version of the Jupyter Notebook installed. It worked for me (I am using Ubuntu 22.04 pre release).

Type the following in terminal: `pip install notebook==5.6.0`

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu switched Firefox to a snap in 21.10. Snaps can't open files under directories that are hidden in your home directory, like ~/.local.

I have the same issue and am hoping for a solution less drastic than removing the snap and reinstalling Firefox using apt.

Comment: More discussion here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1389798/how-to-correctly-configure-snapd-firefox-to-open-local-html-file-generated-by