# Jupyterlab in Docker - Permission demined error on Linux to due to Jupyter not generating .local/share directory

Tags: docker, jupyter, jupyter-lab

**Objective:** Currently creating a dockerfile using [jupyter/base-notebook](https://jupyter-docker-stacks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using/selecting.html#jupyter-base-notebook), and I want to make sure that my environment can run in Windows, macOS, and Linux.

**Issue:** In theory, docker should not have an issue running in any OS. However, I encountered a following `permission denied` error when I was running on Linux:

```bash
 pwd
+ docker run -it --rm -p 8888:8888 -v /home/<username>/myDocker:/home/jovyan myDocker:latest
[I 2022-07-18 18:01:42.359 ServerApp] jupyterlab | extension was successfully linked.
[W 2022-07-18 18:01:42.363 NotebookApp] 'ip' has moved from NotebookApp to ServerApp. This config will be passed to ServerApp. Be sure to update your config before our next release.
[W 2022-07-18 18:01:42.364 NotebookApp] 'port' has moved from NotebookApp to ServerApp. This config will be passed to ServerApp. Be sure to update your config before our next release.
[W 2022-07-18 18:01:42.364 NotebookApp] 'port' has moved from NotebookApp to ServerApp. This config will be passed to ServerApp. Be sure to update your config before our next release.
[I 2022-07-18 18:01:42.371 ServerApp] nbclassic | extension was successfully linked.
[W 2022-07-18 18:01:42.372 ServerApp] [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/jovyan/.local/share'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py", line 645, in get
    value = obj._trait_values[self.name]
KeyError: 'runtime_dir'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/conda/bin/jupyter-lab", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyter_server/extension/application.py", line 584, in launch_instance
    serverapp = cls.initialize_server(argv=args)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyter_server/extension/application.py", line 554, in initialize_server
    serverapp.initialize(
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 110, in inner
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyter_server/serverapp.py", line 2462, in initialize
    self.init_configurables()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyter_server/serverapp.py", line 1865, in init_configurables
    connection_dir=self.runtime_dir,
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py", line 686, in __get__
    return self.get(obj, cls)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py", line 648, in get
    default = obj.trait_defaults(self.name)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py", line 1752, in trait_defaults
    return self._get_trait_default_generator(names[0])(self)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyter_core/application.py", line 106, in _runtime_dir_default
    ensure_dir_exists(rd, mode=0o700)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyter_core/utils/__init__.py", line 12, in ensure_dir_exists
    os.makedirs(path, mode=mode)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/os.py", line 215, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, exist_ok=exist_ok)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/os.py", line 215, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, exist_ok=exist_ok)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/os.py", line 225, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/jovyan/.local/share'
```

Where the main culprit of this is that `.local/share` is not being generated upon running `dockerfile` when ran on Linux (Ubuntu and RedHat). Surprisingly, when I run this on my Windows (via WSL2 - Ubuntu) and on macOS, it does generate `.local/share` and does not get this error.

**Setup:** My dockerfile looks something like this:

```
FROM jupyter/base-notebook:latest

USER root 
USER jovyan 

RUN set -ve

USER jovyan
EXPOSE 8888

ENTRYPOINT jupyter lab --no-browser --allow-root
```

**Note: My dockerfile has more content, but commented out most of them for debugging purpose.*

Commands that I am using to build & run above dockerfile is following:

```bash
docker build -f <path_to_dockerfile> -t myDocker:latest .

docker run -it --rm -p 8888:8888 -v $(pwd):/home/jovyan myDocker:latest
```

Even after testing with above minimalistic dockerfile, Windows version would still generate the `.local/share/...` while giving me the `permission denied` error on Linux.

**What I've tried:**
So far, I've tried manually generating `.local/share`, which would get another `permission denined` error since it needs an additional directories (`.local/share/jupyter/runtime/...`).

New error looks something like this:

```bash
# new error 1
[I 2022-07-18 18:38:01.260 ServerApp] Writing Jupyter server cookie secret to /home/jovyan/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/jupyter_cookie_secret
[E 2022-07-18 18:38:01.260 ServerApp] Failed to write cookie secret to /home/jovyan/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/jupyter_cookie_secret: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/jovyan/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/jupyter_cookie_secret'
/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/IPython/paths.py:70: UserWarning: IPython parent '/home/jovyan' is not a writable location, using a temp directory.
  warn("IPython parent '{0}' is not a writable location,"

# new error 2
[E 2022-07-18 18:38:01.580 ServerApp] Failed to write server-info to /home/jovyan/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/jpserver-1.json: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/jovyan/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/jpserver-1.json'
```

Generating `jpserver-1.json` manually will still yield a permission error.

Additionally, I've used `ls -la` to check the permission status of every directory I have, and they all have same permission setting.

I've also referenced [post with similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46272924/8605939) and used `chown` like following:

```bash
chown -R jovyan:users ~/.local/share/jupyter
```

but this did not solve issue as `permission denied` error comes from non-existing directories/files.

**Question:** What would I need to do so that Linux would generate `.local/share/...` to prevent `permission denied` error? Preferably, I would like to avoid generating `.local/share/...` manually.

Thank you in advance for your help.

**Small Update:**
I've tried manually creating all missing files, such as:

```bash
.local/share/jupyter/runtime/jpserver-#.jp
.local/share/jupyter/runtime/jupyter_cookie_secret
```

and provided additional permission using:

```bash
chmod -R 777 .local/share/
```

and ran this whole thing, and it started working. However, it doesn't perfectly work as in it's still not generating essential directory, such as `.jupyter`.

Furthermore, I'd like to avoid this method as `#` in `jpserver-#.jp` is randomly generated, thus I won't be able to automatically generate these essential directories.

My speculation is that it's a path issue where `jupyter` is automatically generating essential directory, such as `.local/share`, `.jupyter`, etc. into different location.

Answer (score 0):

Not the best solution, but I found a workaround in case anyone has the same issue:

Essentially, what I did was I gave full access to a directory that I'm working on, i.e.

```bash
sudo chmod -R 777 <top_of_directory>
```

From a security standpoint, this may not be the most optimal solution, but neither `755` nor running them via `sudo -s` did not work for some reason.

Please note that while this solution is satisfactory for my case, it may not be  the best solution for someone with same issue.