# Jupyter in Conda: "Error Permission denied: Untitled.ipynb"

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda

**Issue:**

If I begin a Jupyter session in a Conda environment by typing the following into Mac Terminal: `(myenv-env) myusername@myname-MBP ~ % jupyter lab`, Jupyter opens with no issues.

If I change the directory to just one level down, e.g.: `(myenv-env) myusername@myname-MBP ~ % cd ~/Users/myname/Documents` and then try to run Jupyter again by typing: `(myenv-env) myusername@myname-MBP Documents ~ % jupyter lab`, Jupyter will open, but then I'll receive this error: `"Error Permission Denied: Untitled.ipynb."`

I understand this may be a permissions issue. But when I right-click on both of those folders (i.e. `~/Users/myname/` and `~/Users/myname/Documents`) and view the folders' permissions by selecting "Get Info," I can see that I have "Read & Write" permissions on both folders.

So why is Jupyter being denied creating an empty new notebook in my documents folder? (or any other folder further inside my documents folder?) but is able to create one in `~/Users/myname/`?

---

**I Tried:**

I thought this answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46272924/1899063 so I tried it:

```
myusername@myname-MBP-2 ~ % sudo chown -R myusername: ~/.local/share/jupyter
```

But I received the error:

```
chown: /Users/myusername/.local/share/jupyter: No such file or directory
```

and I don't understand it well enough to improvise...