# Jupyter notebook + Chrome - autocomplete problem

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I have installed 6.0.1 version of jupyter notebook, update all packages (conda update --all) and use it in Chrome browser. But I haven't the autocomplete after I press TAB button. I was looking for a problem, but nothing found. Is there a way to find a problem why autocomplete doesn't work?

Comment: Maybe you can refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58060813/7813311).

Answer (score 1):

This workaround solution should help you:

```
%config IPCompleter.greedy=True
```

Reference: https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/2435

Comment: This solution worked for me, when adding %config Completer.use_jedi = False or reverting to jedi 0.17.2 did not.