# jupyter notebook displaying a html code and not opening in the broswer

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I just installed anaconda and I'm trying to open Jupyter notebook but the next code showing up in a notepad:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;url=http://localhost:8890/tree?token=*the real token*" />
    <title>Opening Jupyter Notebook</title>
    <script>
      setTimeout(function() {
        window.location.href = "http://localhost:8890/tree?token=*the real token*";
      }, 1000);
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<p>
    This page should redirect you to Jupyter Notebook. If it doesn't,
    <a href="http://localhost:8890/tree?token=*the real token*">click here to go to Jupyter</a>.
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

if I copy the url it is working but I want to open jupyter from the anaconda navigator and i don't know how to fix it. I searched on google the issue and i couldn't find any method that solves it

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the default configuration is corrupt somehow

Try the solution posted in this StackOverflow post.

[How to change the default browser used by the ipython/jupyter notebook in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35229604/how-to-change-the-default-browser-used-by-the-ipython-jupyter-notebook-in-linux)

You can set which browser to use to open the jupyter notebook.

Comment: Thank you it worked. just a note since I'm using windows the dashes should be '/' and not the default of windows which is '\'.

Answer (score 0):

The problem jupyter notebook default browser is corrupt. The reason here is that when you run the jupyter notebook in anaconda, jupyter will automatically open the file .html with vscode or notepad, or something else... To solve this, you can find that .html file or create a random .html file --> right click --> 'properties' --> 'open with' your browser which you want it to open

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).