# 1. How to open Chrome as default browser from Python-based AI code? Right now it opens Internet explorer by default

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence

while coding a Python-based AI when we are to access the internet through it. The Default web browser opens is Internet Explorer. How to get chrome as default?

Comment: It would help if you provided at least a sample of the code used for opening the browser.

Comment: I think changing your default browser on your OS should fix this. If you're using anaconda/jupyter, use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47772157/how-to-change-the-default-browser-used-by-jupyter-notebook-in-windows).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the specifics of how your AI framework opens a browser nor the operating system you are using. I am using windows 10 and have installed Chrome in the default location.

Changing your default browser using the operating system, may work:

- Open *Default apps*
- Under *Web browser*, select the browser currently listed, and then select *Google Chrome*

Or you can use this method - it works even if chrome isn't your default browser:

```py
import webbrowser

url = 'https://www.python.org'
path = 'C:/Program Files/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe'
webbrowser.register('mybrowser', None, webbrowser.BackgroundBrowser(path))
webbrowser.get('mybrowser').open(url)
```

You can fetch the location of the chrome executable from the registry with the key:

```
HKML\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\chrome.exe
```

Or find it using the shell command:

```
dir /s /b \chrome.exe
```

See also:
[How to change the default browser used by jupyter in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47772157/how-to-change-the-default-browser-used-by-jupyter-notebook-in-windows)
[How to change the default browser used by jupyter in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35229604/how-to-change-the-default-browser-used-by-the-ipython-jupyter-notebook-in-linux)
[Change your default browser in Windows 10](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/change-your-default-browser-in-windows-10-020c58c6-7d77-797a-b74e-8f07946c5db6)