# how to open jupyterlab in different (non default) browser?

Tags: jupyter-lab

I normally start JupyterLab on my Mac by typing `jupyter lab` in a Terminal window. This opens JupyterLab in Safari, as that is my default browser.
My question is: How do I start JupyterLab in another browser, like Chrome, without setting Chrome as my default browser? I imagine that there is a command that I can use in the Terminal to specify which browser JupyterLab should use.

Comment: Update default browser for Jupyter only? https://stackoverflow.com/q/47772157/11613622 or https://stackoverflow.com/q/35229604/11613622

Comment: Thanks! That is a decent work-around, but I was hoping for a simple terminal command to specify the browser for a one-time session (it is just to verify things are working the same in another browser).

Comment: Scroll down on that thread. You can pass that as `--browser` in argument too.

Comment: Silly me. Should have kept reading. Will try that.