# Python: how to open default browser using webbrowser module?

Tags: python

So I'm fairly new to the language, and I wanted to play music from a site.
Using the webbrowser module, I executed the code below I was told that it will open the site in the default browser.

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open("Youtube.com")
```

It works just as expected but opens the site using the almighty Internet Explorer
which, we all know is no one's default browser. If it helps in anyway, my default browser is Google Chrome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [`get()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/webbrowser.html#webbrowser.get):

```
webbrowser.get('chrome').open('https://www.youtube.com')
```

**EDIT**

Make sure to use the full path to the site

Comment: It just executes and nothing happens

Comment: Did you add a controller type ?

Comment: @JoshThePythonDweller Try updated answer.

Comment: this will work just for chrome. what if user has any other browser ???

Comment: Well he asked for chrome so I added a solution for it. If you want another browser, follow my link to `get()` and change the controller type. So it is not just for chrome

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
>>> import webbrowser
>>> browser_path = "C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe %s"
>>> url = "https://www.youtube.com"
>>> webbrowser.get(browser_path).open(url)
True
```

Note the Unix-style path. [This is because webbrowser internally does a shlex.split on the path, which will just erase Windows-style path separators](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24873636/8709791)

[Registering](https://docs.python.org/3/library/webbrowser.html#webbrowser.register) the browser also works on Windows:

```
>>> import webbrowser as wb
>>> wb.register('chrome', None)
>>> wb.open('https://www.youtube.com')
True
>>> wb.open('https://www.google.com')
True
>>> wb.open('https://stackoverflow.com')
True
```

Comment: Both are not working. still opening the same explorer browser

Answer (score 0):

use

```
import webbrowser as wb
wb.get('windows-default').open('Youtube.com'
```

For a particular browser, you can try using:

```
wb.get('chrome %s').open('Youtube.com') # for chrome
```

Comment: I tried both, the application just executes and nothing happens

Comment: is there any error ?

Comment: none, just blank...