# How do i use webbrowser.get() to open URLs in specific browsers?

Tags: python, python-webbrowser

When I run:

```py
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open("facebook.com")
```

It opens facebook on my default browser, but if try to specify a browser using:

```py
import webbrowser
chrome = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe %s"
webbrowser.get(chrome).open("facebook.com")
```

It doesn't open anything (doesn't show any error messages either).
Does anyone know why it doesn't open anything in the second example?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to use the full path to the website

try: "https://www.facebook.com/" instead of "facebook.com"

that is: `webbrowser.get(chrome).open("https://www.facebook.com/")`

Refer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47118598/python-how-to-open-default-browser-using-webbrowser-module) where a similar problem has been discussed

Answer (score 0):

From [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/webbrowser.html#webbrowser.get) you can use an already registered chrome.

> webbrowser.get('chrome')

other than this use the full URL as told by Muhd