# Why can I not find google chrome with python webrowser?

Tags: python

```
import webbrowser

Chrome = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe'

webbrowser.get(Chrome).open("haveibeenpwned.com")
```

Whenever I try I get this "could not locate runnable browser"

P.S: I'm tryna learn python

Comment: As @"Erec Aizen" stated, it is better to use the unix style notation (like also often used in java). If you want to use backslashes, you should at least either double the backslashes or mark the path string as raw string, so python does not interpret the backslashes as escape chars. This means, just add a r directly before the string `Chrome=r'C\Program...`. Just try `print('c:\Program Files (x86)\newDir')` in python and see, what happens.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: generic webbrowser.get().open() for chrome.exe does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24873302/python-generic-webbrowser-get-open-for-chrome-exe-does-not-work)

Answer (score 0):

You should register it first.

```
webbrowser.register('chrome', None,webbrowser.BackgroundBrowser(Chrome), 1)
webbrowser.get('chrome').open_new_tab("haveibeenpwned.com")
```

Comment: my new code is https://pastebin.com/raw/iwxeDg3E but it still doesn't work

Comment: @Several `webbrowser.get('chrome').open_new_tab("haveibeenpwned.com")`

Comment: It does for me.

Comment: i get this whenver i do it https://pastebin.com/raw/XvF4baWx

Answer (score 0):

You should use UNIX-style path: common slashes instead of backslashes.

```py
import webbrowser

chrome = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe'

webbrowser.get(chrome).open("haveibeenpwned.com")
```

Comment: still doesn't work pretty sure the unix style doesn't matter

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the problem is the spaces in your path. You need to insert a final `%s` at the end of your path to make it work. No need to register the browser name first.

```
webbrowser.get(
    "C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe %s"
).open("haveibeenpwned.com")
```

As seen here:
[Python: generic webbrowser.get().open() for chrome.exe does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24873302/python-generic-webbrowser-get-open-for-chrome-exe-does-not-work)

Comment: Thanks! I just added import webbroswer to your script and it worked!

Comment: Very glad I could help. I you later can mark mine as the accepted answer I'll even more glad :D