# sikuli script python jython import subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess, jython, sikuli, sikuli-ide

Looking for documentation that would illuminate a particular line of python code.  Could you please provided a resource for it?

```
subprocess.Popen("start chrome /new-tab www.google.com",shell = True)
```

Specifically, how was this composed?
**"start chrome /new-tab www.google.com"**

Would have liked to have asked the question here, but lacked sufficient points: [How can I open a new browser tab with subprocess?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35987882/how-can-i-open-a-new-browser-tab-with-subprocess)
*Thanks for the initial answer @DineshKumar, just need more information!*

Answer (score 0):

```
subprocess.Popen
```

docs can be found in the official Jython docs (preferably) or the Python 2.7 docs

```
start chrome /new-tab www.google.com
```

is the Windows `start` command