# popen.kill not closing browser window

Tags: python, subprocess, popen, kill

I have spent the past few days trying to automate the process of flattening a PDF and this function is the one I have found works best. The only issue is that the a.kill() command is not being read, resulting in the browser remaining open after the function is complete. How can I close the browser window after the save process is finished?

```
import time
import subprocess
import keyboard

def chrome():
    test = "test"
    name = "file:///C://Users//akcgo//Documents//CARB//ARBER//PDFS//Company A.pdf"
    a = subprocess.Popen("C://Program Files (x86)//Google//Chrome//Application//chrome.exe")
    time.sleep(1)
    keyboard.write(name)
    time.sleep(1)
    keyboard.press_and_release('enter')
    time.sleep(1)
    keyboard.press_and_release(['ctrl', 'p'])
    time.sleep(1)
    keyboard.press_and_release('enter')
    time.sleep(1)
    keyboard.write(test)
    time.sleep(.5)
    keyboard.press_and_release('enter')
    time.sleep(2)
    a.kill()
    # keyboard.press_and_release(['ctrl', 'w']) doesn't work either
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get the subprocess' PID by using `pid = a.pid`, then calling `os.kill(pid, signal.SIGTERM)` or `os.kill(pid, signal.SIGKILL)`.

Comment: It is saying ``` PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied` ``

Comment: Try to launch the Python script with admin rights.

Comment: Thank you! Is there any possible way to close it without admin rights?

Comment: Yes, there might be another solution: just launch `os.system("Taskkill /PID %d /F" % pid)`, where variable `pid` contains the process id.

Comment: got this message: ERROR: The process "21436" not found.

Comment: That means that the process is already gone at the time you invoke that call.

Comment: Google chrome doesn't close properly so how can the process be gone?

Comment: I have no clue...perhaps it doesn't find the PID because you don't have access to it, since you're taskkilling without admin rights?