# webbrowser not opening new windows

Tags: python, python-webbrowser

I just got a new job working remotely and I have to start my day by opening a bunch of pages and logging into them.  I would love to automate this process as it can be kind of tedious.  I would like to leave my personal browsing window alone and open a new window with all of the pages I need.  Here is the gist of what I'm trying to do:

```
import webbrowser
first = True
chromePath = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe %s'
URLS = ("first page", "second page", "third page")
for url in URLS:
    if first:
        webbrowser.get(chromePath).open(url)
        first = False
    else:
        webbrowser.open(url, new=2)
```

For some reason this code is just opening new tabs in my current browser, which is basically the opposite of what I want it to be doing.  What is going on?

Comment: Do you want to open every url in a separate window or launch one new window with all the tabs inside?

Comment: New window with all tabs.

Comment: I suspect you have chrome set up to create tabs for new pages insead of opening a new browser.  Perhaps use another browser (firefox) for your automated load set-up?

Answer (score 2):

I don't have Chrome installed, but there seem to be multiple problems:

1. According to the docs, `webbrowser.get` expects the name of the browser, not the path.
2. You should save the return value of `webbrowser.get()` and use it to open the remaining urls.

```
import webbrowser
URLS = ("first page", "second page", "third page")
browser= webbrowser.get('chrome')
first= True
for url in URLS:
    if first:
        browser.open_new(url)
        first = False
    else:
        browser.open_new_tab(url)
```

Comment: thanks for the intention, but this is not the solution of the problem. you can concatenate/split methods, but the result is going to be the same than webbrowser.get(chromepPath).open(url). regards

Answer (score 2):

May be too late, but probably will help others.

As per the docs, you should try with *new=1*

> webbrowser.open(url, new=0, autoraise=True)
>
> Display url using the default browser. If new is 0, the url is opened
> in the same browser window if possible. If new is 1, a new browser
> window is opened if possible. If new is 2, a new browser page (“tab”)
> is opened if possible. If autoraise is True, the window is raised if
> possible (note that under many window managers this will occur
> regardless of the setting of this variable).

Doc link: [Webbrowser docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/webbrowser.html)

Comment: I saw this in the docs as well, but never saw it change anything.  Can anyone else confirm this worked for them?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar issue. I just used os.system() to open a new instance of chrome. Also I registered the chrome.exe as a new browser using:

```
#register the browser
chrome_path = "C:\\Users\\cj9250\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe"
webbrowser.register('chrome', None,webbrowser.BackgroundBrowser(chrome_path),1)
```

There is guidance in [other posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22445217/python-webbrowser-open-to-open-chrome-browser) on using .get to call the path to chrome. Despite trying this method and many other different methods, I just could not get chrome to open a new window and session.

Finally I came to os.system to open a new instance of chrome. So for your code it would look like this:

```
import webbrowser
import os #use for new instance of chrome

#urls I want to open in array
URLS = (
        "first page", 
        "second page", 
        "third page"
        )

#register the browser
chrome_path = "YOUR PATH TO CHROME\\chrome.exe" #note the double \ syntax
webbrowser.register('chrome', None,webbrowser.BackgroundBrowser(chrome_path),1)

#open new instance of chrome
os.system(r'YOUR PATH TO CHROME\chrome.exe')

#open each url
for url in URLS:
    webbrowser.get('chrome').open(url)
```

Looking at what you're trying to do, I think that Selenium would be much better suited. I too use a web application daily for work, and I took the time to run through some Selenium tutorials. It has been much simpler for automation.

Comment: Two notes regarding this. **First**: you need to take browser path in quotes again in `os.system` call. That is because path might contain spaces. e.g. `os.system(r'"C:\Program Files\...\chrome.exe"')`. **Second:** it is okay to call `webbrowser.open_new_tab("<url>")` without needing to *register* a browser first, **after** you call `os.system(...)`.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is much simpler. Assuming that you have standard path ubication for chrome.exe (and your OS is windows), this is the solution (it opens a new chrome window even if you already had one previously opened). `subprocess` instead of `os.system` is mandatory bc otherwise it doesn't open a new chrome window if had one already opened. regards

```
import subprocess
urL         ='https://www.google.com'
chrome_path ="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe"
child       = subprocess.Popen(chrome_path, shell=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

This was done on a Windows machine.

I was facing basically the same issue; not being able to open a new browsing **window** and only being able to open new tabs.

Here's a workaround that allowed me to open a **new** browsing **window** (in Chrome) with an initial URL and then open subsequent URLs in that window as tabs.

```py
import webbrowser
import subprocess

# Set this appropriately depending on your situation
chrome_path = 'C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe'
first_url = 'https://www.google.com/'

# This should open a NEW WINDOW with the URL specified above
command = f"cmd /C \"{chrome_path}\" {first_url} --new-window"

# Alternative way that achieves the same result
# command = f"cmd /C start chrome {first_url} --new-window"

subprocess.Popen(command)

new_tab_urls = [
    'https://www.python.org/',
    'https://hackernoon.com/30-jokes-only-programmers-will-get-a901e1cea549'
]

for url in new_tab_urls:
    webbrowser.open_new_tab(url)
```