# webbrowser.get — could not locate runnable browser

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I am trying to access the internet with Google Chrome but every time I use `webbrowser.open(url)` it opens IE.

So I checked to make sure I have Chrome as my default, which I do, and I tried using the `get()` function to link the actual Chrome application but it gives me this error instead:

> File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\webbrowser.py", line 51, in get raise Error("could not locate runnable browser") webbrowser.Error: could not locate runnable browser

I also tried to open other browsers but it gives the same error. It also reads IE as my default and only runnable browser.

What could be happening? Is there an alternative?

Using Python 3.6.

Comment: Are you using selenium?

Comment: I am just using the webbrowser module.

Comment: I notice if you have *http* prefix, it will opens in Chrome, without the prefix, IE. Meaning *h t t p://google.com* -> chrome, *google.com* -> IE

Answer (score 24):

I too faced the same problem. What you can do is to register the browser and then launch a new tab. Something like this:

```
import webbrowser    
urL='https://www.google.com'
chrome_path="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe"
webbrowser.register('chrome', None,webbrowser.BackgroundBrowser(chrome_path),1)
webbrowser.get('chrome').open_new_tab(urL)
```

And it works. From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/webbrowser.html#webbrowser.register) webbrowser.register(name, constructor, instance=None).

Comment: This should nail the OP (+1)

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not working for me. @Hai Vu's suggestion does work but when I try to open it on a new window with the webbrowser.open_new(URL) or webbrowser.open(URL,1) function, it only opens a new tab.

Comment: I had to remove the final `1` argument on the call the `register()` function for it to work.

Comment: @Maxied try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61752842/3572505

Answer (score 4):

I found a solution. Put a '%s' after the path of your browser.
For example; change this:

```
 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
```

to this:

```
 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe %s"
```

This has worked for me.

Comment: This worked for me on Linux Mint 20. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

use "http://" in url

that works for me

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me

```
url = "https://www.google.com"
chrome_path = "C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe"
webbrowser.register("chrome", None, webbrowser.BackgroundBrowser(chrome_path))
webbrowser.get("chrome").open_new(url)
```