# Getting "no runnable browser detected" when opening Opera with webbrowser

Tags: python, webbrowser-control, python-webbrowser

```
List=['google.com','facebook.com','youtube.com']
c = webbrowser.get('opera') 
for i in List:
    c.open(i)
```

I am using Sublime text and then running the code in cmd. I am trying this for a long time but it says, no runnable browser detected. Please tell what browser name should be put inside that module to open only opera webbrowser.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [webbrowser.get — could not locate runnable browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48056052/webbrowser-get-could-not-locate-runnable-browser)

Answer (score 0):

```
List=['google.com','facebook.com','youtube.com'] 
       
c = webbrowser.get('opera')

webbrowser.register('opera',"location of your opera exe file",c) 
for i in List: 
    c.open(i)
```