# Python: Constructing search URL from OCR

Tags: python, shell

I want to take text I have from scanning an OCR and construct an URL from it and search through chrome in python.  I know I need to use

```
query_encoded = urllib.parse.quote_plus(query)
```

However I do not know how to implement this and opening chrome and searching through google.

Comment: You can refer this link to open URL to the chrome https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22445217/python-webbrowser-open-to-open-chrome-browser

Comment: For OCR you can use existing libraries or you can use Machine Learning to train and achieve what you want

Answer (score 0):

You may use of selenium which is use for browser automaton, you can solve your problem using this. [example](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html#simple-usage). There is no restriction of browser, you can use any browser with it's webdriver.