# Getting TypeError when attempting to open Chrome using Webbrowser - Python

Tags: python, module, typeerror

I came across another question asking how to open Chrome using `webbrowser`, and I wanted to do it for myself.

[Python webbrowser.open() to open Chrome browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22445217/python-webbrowser-open-to-open-chrome-browser)

I have a variable saved in the module called `Chrome`

```
Chrome = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe %s"
```

I did this so I could perform this code:

```
import webbrowser as wb
from webbrowser import Chrome

wb.get(Chrome).open('Google.com')
```

When I run this code, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
wb.get(Chrome).open('google.com')
File "C:\Users\MY USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37- 
32\Lib\webbrowser.py", line 50, in get
if '%s' in browser:
TypeError: argument of type 'type' is not iterable
```

Why isn't this working? I'm running Python 3.7.

Answer (score 1):

You're using `Chrome` in two different ways:

```
Chrome = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe %s"
```

and

```
from webbrowser import Chrome
```

Since you can't have two things named `Chrome` in the same namespace, one is clobbering the other. In this case, `Chrome` from the `webbrowser` module is clobbering the string pointing to your local Chrome browser.

Use different names for each thing, e.g.

```
import webbrowser

chrome = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe %s'
webbrowser.get(chrome).open('google.com')
```

Alternatively, something like this will probably work since [Python already knows about a bunch of browsers](https://docs.python.org/3/library/webbrowser.html#module-webbrowser) (I don't have a Windows machine to test on right now):

```
from webbrowser import Chrome

# Find a Chrome-family browser whose binary name is chrome
chrome = Chrome('chrome')  # chrome = Chrome('chromium') works on my Linux machine
chrome.open('google.com')
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried

```
import webbrowser as wb
Chrome = 'open -a /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app %s'
wb.get(Chrome).open('http://google.com')
```

and it worked. The differences here are my url and my path. I work on MacOS and so the path my browser is different. Maybe you could check if your browser path is correct?

Can you try this path?

```
C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe %s
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. I tried that code and it yielded the same error.