# How to open a specific link in chrome using python

Tags: python

Though the default browser is IE or Firefox, when I run the program, I want the website to be opened in chrome.
At first, I tried this out--

```
import webbrowser
import os
path = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application %s"
webbrowser.get(path).open("youtube.com")
```

But the webpage opened in Ie as my default browser is IE.

Then I tried the below code-

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser =   webdriver.Chrome()
browser.open('https://directory.corp.intranet/cmsviewer/login.html')
```

But received many errors. Please help me out!!!

Comment: duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22445217/python-webbrowser-open-to-open-chrome-browser

Answer (score 1):

Hello and welcome to Stack overflow

try to do this :

```
import webbrowser
chrome_path = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe %s'
webbrowser.get(chrome_path).open('http://docs.python.org/')
```

good luck

Answer (score 1):

Try maybe the following:

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.get('chrome').open("youtube.com")
```

As it seems that chrome is already registered by default: 
https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/webbrowser.html#webbrowser.register

Answer (score 0):

Your selenium code is very likely not working due to the lack web extensions like `.net, .com,.org, .aspx` etc. So your selenium code should work if it looked like

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser =   webdriver.Chrome()
browser.open('https://directory.corp.intranet.aspx')
```