# Python webbrowser.open() not working in VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-webbrowser

I am trying to open a webpage using Python, and my editor is VS Code.

This is the code:

```
import webbrowser

webbrowser.open('google.com')
```

This won't work while using VS Code, but it does work when I'm using IDLE.

What am I misunderstanding? What have I not done/done incorrectly? I have the Open in Browser extension by TechER, but even with this, I can't open a web browser page while using VS Code, and nothing I've found has been remotely helpful or even hints at what to do.

I'm clearly  missing something in VS Code, but I don't have even the slightest clue as to what.

Comment: What does "won't work" mean? Do you get an error message or does the script silently exit?

Comment: Works normally for me whether I do it with the interactive shell or run a script (via vscode terminal) with no extensions. How are you running it exactly?

Comment: What I mean by "won't work" is as I say in the question. I can't open a web browser. No errors, but no webpage. I placed a print('finished') the line following webbrowser.open('google.com') and my print statement is working. So it's not a problem with the code, it's a a problem with webbrowser not opening a webpage. This exact line of code works in IDLE, but not in VScode.

Comment: Please have a look at this question and see if the answer could help you: [Python webbrowser.open() to open Chrome browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22445217/python-webbrowser-open-to-open-chrome-browser).

Comment: You *do not* `say in the question`: `I can't open a web browser`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check which interpreter is VSCode using because sometimes VSCode downloads the interpreter somewhere else. To change the environment of VSCode you can take a look at https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments

Answer (score 0):

Just Set Your Browser:

```
import webbrowser

firefoxPath = "C:/Program Files/Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe %s"

webbrowser.get(firefoxPath).open(firstUrl)
```

in VScode